# Adobe Libraries and Creative Cloud storage

Tags: creative-cloud, library

this is probably gonna get comments like 'it belongs in Adobe forums' etc. but:

Does anyone know why CC -Libraries- and CC -file storage- are two different entities? I've been trying lately to start using libraries but I find it very cumbersome. IMO it should just be one space and you should be able to browse all content from the various Adobe Apps' libraries panel. Or maybe getting rid of the individual panels in each app and just have one app that interacts with all apps. (Like f.ex. pulling out CC Bridge and make it useful. Does anyone use Bridge?) I've been trying to look at learning material to find out what's a good way to use it, but I really can't see it.
Also I've been trying to upload multiple files to libraries at once from desktop, but it doesn't seem possible? I can only upload an open document? So I have to individually open, say 30 images in PS and then add each to library? Appreciate any useful hints on workflow with libaries, thanks.

Comment: This is broad list of questions and offtopic. Simply referring to technical issues related to Adobe products does not make it a graphic design question. Superuser is more suited for your question(s).

Answer (score 3):

I only use libraries when I want the content to be available to me on another machine, or in another application (although rarely), and I use the storage for distributing finished files to others or when I want access on another machine.

When working locally, I have little or no need for either libraries or storage.

Adobe isn't forcing anyone to use these features. If you find them useful, use them. If not then don't. Store you content locally if it suits you better.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose behind Libraries is to store crucial assets and styles so that you can reuse them easily. Think of it as Brand-Component storage.

So the purpose is not to store a whole brochure in it, but rather to make one for each client and store all their logos and brand-specific assets for easy selection.

I usually use folders for this (I have been doing stuff like this for a gabillion years and the libraries become obsolete on the whims of developers), but the idea is there.

In ye olden days, I would have an actual folder of items that might contain photostats of the *Corpora-Cola* logo in 5 sizes etc. for me to use in paste-up. The libraries are the location you store these fixed unchanging assets.